# Script on google sheet for filtering a specific name

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-macros

need some help with script on google sheets

I'm having some issues to try to use "**setVisibleValues**" and I got an error saying "**Exception: Visible values are not currently supported. As an alternative specify a list of hidden values that excludes the values that should be visible.**". But my problem is, I've a huge number of employee names on a list, and I wanna filter just based in one person.

I cant show some information, but the thing is: "I just wanna filter one value, and I don't know how to do it using "**setHiddenValues**".

```
function Filtersheet() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  spreadsheet.getRange('A3:S').activate();

  spreadsheet.getRange('H3').activate();

  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()

  .setHiddenValues([''])

  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()

  .setVisibleValues(['tayzer'])

  .build();

  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(8, criteria);

}
```

Lets say that the names of the Employees are : jorge, lucas, nuno, fernando, marta, beatriz, tayzer, larissa, and I wanna use the filter script to only show on the column the information related to **tayzer**

But my way to change the filter employee will be on a cell outside the script (cause I've around 200 employees)

**Thanks in advance for the help**

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function setFilter() {
// replace 'sheet name' with you sheet
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet name');
var range = ss.getDataRange();
var filter = range.getFilter() || range.createFilter()
var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextContains('tayzer');
filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(8, criteria);
}
```

if i am not wrong if you put "jorge" in cell_C4 you want it to filter "jorge" in column E, if so try below code.

```
function setFilter() {
// replace 'sheet name' with you sheet
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet name');
var range = ss.getDataRange();
var filter = range.getFilter() || range.createFilter()
var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextContains(ss.getRange('C4').getValue()).build();
filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(8,criteria)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Shiva, it worked!!!! just a question, is possible to change the **whenTextContains('tayzer')** to find this text on a external cell? Like **whenTextContains(__cell 'C4'__)** 

Because I've around 200 employee names and if I can find this text contains from a external cell, it gonna help me a lot!!

Comment: Please accept the answer if it works it will help the community. If you have few emloyees name to hide use `.setHiddenvalues([name1,name2...])` instead of  `.whenTextContains()` to put the employees name in an array use `getrange('range')` & `Logger.log(assigned var)` to make it easy

Comment: Thanks Shiva, I'm gonna tryied this one, but a doubt (sorry again), with the `getrange('range')` & `Logger.log(assigned var)` I can use a spefic cell? like to take the range of employee that are on the cell C4

Comment: yes you will get value of cells inside range use `getRnge('range').getvalues();` and log it you can put that array for fillter criteria. If its one cell provided script will do if its big range log it and put the array. If i am not clear provide data(Not confidential) il do it for you

Comment: Got it Shiva, if you can help, I'll really appreciate.

I have around 200 employees, and the names are in the colummns H, and the name of the employee that I wanna filter is on the C4, is this help?

jorge, lucas, nuno, fernando, marta, beatriz, tayzer, larissa